# I want my form to save the correct info on jQuery, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to keep my existing info when some are missing, the site goes up and everything is erased when info is missing.

I would like the page to remain at the bottom, even if there are errors, and if there is good information that the form retains them

HTML :

```
<footer style="background-color: black;color: white">
    <form>
        <h3>Nous-Joindre</h3>

        <div class="formContainer">

            <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
            <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="Votre Prenom">

            <label for="nom">Nom de Famille</label>
            <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Votre nom de Famille">

            <label for="email">Courriel :</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Courriel@example.com"><br>

            <label for="sujet">Sujet</label>
            <input type="text" name="sujet" id="sujet" placeholder="Sujet"></textarea>

            <label for="subject">Message</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Écrire votre Message ici.."
                style="height:200px"></textarea>

            <input id = "submit" type="submit" value="Envoyer">
        </div>
    </form>

</footer>
```

jQuery - e-mail confirmation:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
let re = /^\w+([-+.'][^\s]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
if ($('#email').val() == '') {
    $('#email').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
}
else if (!re.test($('#email').val())) {
    $('#email').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Courriel Invalide')
}
```

First name confirmation :

```
else if ($('#prenom').val() == '') {
    $('#nom').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
}
```

Name confirmation :

```
else if ($('#nom').val() == '') {
    $('#nom').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
}
```

Subject confirmation :

```
else if ($('#subject').val() == '') {
    $('#subject').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
}
```

Message confirmation :

```
    else if ($('#message').val() == '') {
    $('#message').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
    }
```

If everything is ok, border should go green:

```
    else {
    $('#email').css('border', '2px solid green')
    $('#prenom').css('border', '2px solid green')
    $('#nom').css('border', '2px solid green')
    $('#subject').css('border', '2px solid green');
    $('#message').css('border', '2px solid green');
}
})
```

CSS:

```
.formContainer {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #456542a4, whitesmoke;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

```js
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let re = /^\w+([-+.'][^\s]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
  if ($('#email').val() == '') {
    $('#email').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
  } else if (!re.test($('#email').val())) {
    $('#email').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Courriel Invalide')
  } else if ($('#prenom').val() == '') {
    $('#nom').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
  } else if ($('#nom').val() == '') {
    $('#nom').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
  } else if ($('#subject').val() == '') {
    $('#subject').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
  } else if ($('#message').val() == '') {
    $('#message').css('border', '2px solid red');
    alert('Veuillez remplir tout les champs')
  } else {
    $('#email').css('border', '2px solid green')
    $('#prenom').css('border', '2px solid green')
    $('#nom').css('border', '2px solid green')
    $('#subject').css('border', '2px solid green');
    $('#message').css('border', '2px solid green');
  }
})
```

```css
.formContainer {
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #456542a4, whitesmoke;
padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <h3>Nous-Joindre</h3>

        <div class="formContainer">

            <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
            <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="Votre Prenom">

            <label for="nom">Nom de Famille</label>
            <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Votre nom de Famille">

            <label for="email">Courriel :</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Courriel@example.com"><br>

            <label for="sujet">Sujet</label>
            <input type="text" name="sujet" id="sujet" placeholder="Sujet"></textarea>

            <label for="subject">Message</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Écrire votre Message ici.."
                style="height:200px"></textarea>

            <input id = "submit" type="submit" value="Envoyer">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add preventDefault() after triggering the submit button.
Use this code in your submit trigger option:

```
$("#submit").on("click",function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
});
```